# System Properties Opens at Login for All users on MS 2008 Terminal Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I've looked the normal places, msconfig, run, runonce for something that would prompt this to run at startup and I can't figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas why System Properties would open up every single time someone logs into this server?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Sysinternals - that will give you all the places where things can possibly automatically launch from and show you what launches from there.

Find the System Properties entry and untick the box and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-creating the default profile from a user you have verified all of the "run" locations in the registry are clean, then delete all the users' profiles and let them get re-created from the default one.

Also, look in any logon scripts that might be assigned to any users either through group policy or local policy.

Comment: Tried that already but thanks. I probably just need to reboot the server. Will try that this weekend and see what happens.